# Extract number in a text string

Tags: excel

I am trying to extract rate in $$ from a text string. Please help. LIke in below problem I want to extract only $750

I have tried find formula. Below is the text string:

> "Approved By SET 1: lola amith
>   Approved By SET 2: Chilled Beer
>   Approved By Provider:  Gonan Medical LLC / Tarij
>   Rate: $750.00
>
> Total $750.00 / Rgonga Medical Transportation LLC / Tarij / Stretcher / Out of Area / discussed Rate $80.00 / Miles Included 6.00 / going to pay Rate $1.40 / Leg Miles 23.43 / Special Rated Miles 88.30 / Special Rated Mileage $8.25 / Approval Level Manager"

```
=Find (Text(Right)__
```

I only want $750 in the column but I am getting an error

Comment: Why `$750.00` and not `$80.00`, `$1.40` or `$8.25` Can you explain the logic a little more?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,FIND("Rate: $",A1),FIND("Total $",A1)-FIND("Rate: $",A1)),"Rate: $",""))+0
```

Comment: Never seen the `CLEAN` function used. Vury Nice

Comment: Thanks. It removes all the white and invisible characters, so only the number remains, but presented as text. Then the shorter version to convert it to a number is to coerce it by adding a zero.

Comment: the 0 part went right over my head. Learned me twice. Sorry, cant upvote twice :0

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your first instance of `Rate`. Note this works by extracting the value in between `Rate: $` and `Total` so if your string format is not consistent this will break.

```
=NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("$",A1),FIND("Total",A1)-FIND("$",A1)))
```

Comment: Thanks, the formula is correct but did not work for most of my cells as all cells do not have completed daya

Comment: Put the formula in `IFERROR` then like so: `IFERROR([above formula here], "Incomplete Data")`